# Difference between defining function with def and as a variable in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to achieve method overloading within an object by declaring function with `val`, but it doesn't work as expected (changing `val` to `def` makes no difference):

```
object B {
  val p: (=> Unit) = println(1)
  val p: (Int => Unit) = (i) => println(i) # p is already defined in the scope
}
```

But if I use `def` everything works well:

```
object A {
  def p() = println(1)
  def p(i: Int) = println(i)
}
```

The reason why I'm using the first way is I already have a type alias for a function (let's say `type printit = Int => Unit`, and I'm not sure how to use that `printit` type with `def`.

Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If I invoke `B.p`, what should happen? With a method, it's clear: count the arguments, look at their type, determine which method should be called. How is it supposed to work with `val`? You kind-of answered your own question in the last edit....

Comment: That makes sense. So is there anyway that I can create a method that takes an `Int` and returns `Unit` by just using the `printit` type?

Comment: You can create a `def`/`val` that returns a function value of type `printit`, but each such `def`/`val` must have its own unique signature. `val p: X` and `val p: Y` cannot be distinguished by their inputs, because they take no inputs in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530007/1151929